# c++ get the character i from a wstring

Tags: c++

I have a small problem, but I can't figure out why..

I have a `std::wstring text` with a value of `L"test"`

I then try to print its first character like this:

`OutputDebugString(&text[0]);`

but the result is `test`..

when I use `OutputDebugString(&text[1]);`

The result is `est`

I thought that array access should give me the character at a specified location..
Could anybody tell me what I should do or am doing wrong?

I also tried `.at(i);` with the same result.

Got it:

```
wchar_t st = text[0];

OutputDebugString(&st);
```

Alex Reinking stated that this a a better and more safe solution: (as the string then contains a null terminator)

```
wchar_t st[3] = { text[0], 0x0 };
OutputDebugString(&st[0]);
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: You are taking the *address* of the character and printing that. Remove the `&` to get the character itself.

Comment: `OutputDebugString` takes a null terminated string as it's argument. If you want to print only the first character you'll need to copy it to a string and place the terminator after it.

Comment: Ah, got it:

`wchar_t st = text[0];

OutputDebugString(&st);`

feel noobie now :p

Comment: ^ I'm surprised that works... you're going to need a null terminator after that character. Something like: `wchar_t st[3] = { text[0], 0x0 }` would be more correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because, in memory, the string looks something like this:

```
      V-- &text[0]
addr: 0x80000000 0x80000001 0x80000002 0x80000003 0x80000004
text: t,         e,         s,         t,         0x00
      ^-- text[0]
```

So when you ask for the address of `text[1]` what you get is:

```
      V-- &text[1]
addr: 0x80000001 0x80000002 0x80000003 0x80000004
text: e,         s,         t,         0x00
      ^-- text[1]
```

Which leaves you with `e,x,t,NULL` or the string "ext". The function you're calling will use all the characters up until the terminator.

Comment: Granted, this is assuming a `char*` instead of a `wchar_t*` (which is stored in a wstring), but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 1):

A *string* is a series of characters followed by a null terminator.

The `OutputDebugString` function (and most functions in C and in WinAPI which take strings) accept a pointer to the first character of such a string. The the function keeps printing characters from that location and subsequent locations until it hist the null terminator.

If you only want to act on a single character you either need to call a function which expects a single character, or build a string of length 1 containing that character and a null terminator.

Answer (score 0):

OutputDebugString takes a string, therefore it will start with the address you have given and go all the way until it hits a NULL. To address your specific issue you have to write your own function that will take one character from the string, then put it into a new string, then output that new string.

Answer (score -3):

OutputDebugStringW(text.c_str()); should do what you want

Comment: That is the same as writing `OutputDebugStringW(&text[0])`, which we already established isn't what the OP wanted.